# How to detect if a federated Identity Provider has MFA configured?

Tags: identityserver4, google-iam

I'm planning to federate external Identity Providers (Google,Microsoft,GitHub,...) to my applications.
In my applications for security reasons we want MFA to be enabled for every user.

Is there any way to detect if the user authenticated himself using "Google" with MFA?

I understand that federating an external Idp, the user identification responsibility is transferred to the external Idp, so I doubt that what I'm asking would be possible.

Thanks in advance.
OaicStef

P.S.: In my applications, I manage the authentication with Identity Server 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amr` claim is what you're looking for but it's optional so it's not for certain that all providers will provide it and if they do they may provide the data in different ways - e.g. one might return `["pwd","otp"]` to describe a situation where a password and a one-time code were used and another may just just use `"mfa"`.

The best thing to do would be to experiment and observe what each service does both with and without MFA enabled and adapt as neccessary.

If it's not something you can guarantee then there's also the option of implementing your own MFA features - libs for using TOTP-based authenticator apps or FIDO2/WebAuthn are readily available.